# I don't understand django's 404 display

Tags: django

I want to move to my 404 page when accessing a URL that is not set.
We are trying to implement it in multiple applications.
I tried a few, but I can't.

Where is the best way to write code?

```
#setting
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']
```

```
#project url.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import re_path
from django.views.static import serve

# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
    ]

handler404 = 'person.views.handler404'
handler500 = 'person.views.handler500'
```

```
#application view.py
def handler404(request):
    response = render_to_response('404.html', {},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    response.status_code = 404
    return response


def handler500(request):
    response = render_to_response('500.html', {},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    response.status_code = 500
    return response
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: It does not transition to the 404 page that I created.
And it will transition to the default page.

Comment: did you set `DEBUG = False`? As far as I know this is not activated in development to do better debugging.

Comment: I think debug information will be displayed when debug = True.

Comment: I want to check 404.html created in template.

Comment: I am sorry if the explanation is not communicated.

Comment: Your question remains unclear. You didn't even answer Willem's question: *did* you set debug to false?

Comment: Is DEBUG = False in setting.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `render_to_response`, it's obsolete. Use `render` instead.

```
def handler404(request):
    response = render(request, '404.html', status_code=404)
```

If your tutorial or book is telling you to write this code, then it's out of date, and you should look for a different resource to learn Django.

In your case, the handlers are not doing anything different to the regular handler. Therefore you should unset `handler404` and `handler500`. The default handlers will use your custom `404.html` and `500.html` templates as long as they are in the templates directory.

Comment: And there was a problem with my template.
Thank you very much.